# Closure in topology proof?

Tags: general-topology

I want to prove $A$ is closed iff $\overline{A}=A$;

I need to use the definition of neighbourhoods instead open sets and not use the complement to prove this.

So wondering how can you prove it just using closure I can't see how it is possible.

Edit it asks you to use the definition of closure directly. Suppose that X is a topological space and A is a subset of X. A point $x \in X$ is a closure points of A if for all neighbourhoods N of x, $N\cap A \not= \emptyset$. The set of closure points of A is the closure of A.

Comment: And can you state the definition of a closed set?

Comment: "Compliment" is what you would tell someone in order to flatter them into solving the exercise for you. "Complement" is when you take "everything that is not in the set".

Comment: And what is the definition of closed that you want to use, since you don't want to use "complements"?

Comment: and what is the definition of $\overline{A}$?

Comment: @simplicity Do you know that the closure of a subset A of a topological space X is the intersection of all closed sets that contain A and therefore is the smallest closed set containing A?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $A$ is closed, so that it contains all of its accumulation points. Then $\bar{A}$, which is $A$ together with its accumulation points, is just $A$.

Conversely, if $A = \bar{A}$, then $A$ contains all of its accumulation points. By definition, $A$ is closed.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $\bar{A}:=A\cap\{B:B\subseteq A\text{ is closed}\}$. Therefore if $A$ is closed, its closure will be $A\cap A=A$ since $A$ will be in the set $\{B:B\subseteq A\text{ is closed}\}$ and everything else will just be a subset of $A$. Conversely, assume that $\bar{A}=A$. This means that $A\cap\{B:B\subseteq A\text{ is closed}\}=A$. This can only be true when the set has $A$ and a bunch of subsets of $A$. And this only happens, by definition, when $A$ is closed.